# How can the timeline height be dynamically resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

How can a vis.js timeline height be dynamically resized? I want to increase the height when users collapse other panels, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation about this. I've tried `$(container).height('500px')` and `$(various_visjs_elements).height('500px')` but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

To change the timeline options you can use the setOptions method on the timeline object as documented [Here](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Methods).

> **setOptions(options)**:
>   Set or update options. It is possible to change any option of the timeline at any time. You can for example switch orientation on the fly.

To answer your question you have to keep the reference of the timeline object when it gets created and you can call: `timeline.setOptions({height:"500px"});`

I created a simple [CodePen](https://codepen.io/betim-beja/pen/qygmBX) for this.